# How to set IPAddress as "All Unassigned" using command line?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-services, terminal-services-gateway

I read this [SetIPAndPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/setipandport-win32-tsgatewayserversettings) and tried to set the transport of RD Gateway by using powershell, but it didn't work, here is my command line:

```bsh
$HTTPPort = 7443
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2/TerminalServices -ClassName Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName SetIPAndPort -Arguments @{TransportType = 1; Port = $HTTPPort; OverrideExisting = 1}
```

It returned value `2147749896`, according to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-wmi-provider-error-codes), it means one of the parameters to the call is not correct, so I tried to give full parameters, which including `IPAddress`, but whatever I tried, I just can't assign it as "All Unassigned", I must assigned an IP to pass, that's a big problem to me.

```bsh
@{TransportType = 1; IPAddress = $IPAddress; Port = $HTTPPort; OverrideExisting = 1}
```

"0.0.0.0", "All Unassigned", "All", "Null", "None", "0", all of them can't reach my goal and returned error value `2147749896` or `2147952422`.

**How can I set `IPAddress` as `All Unassigned` by using `SetIPAndPort` command line?**

OS:
Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, use asterisk `*` to set `IPAddress` as `All Unassigned`, like this:

```bsh
@{ TransportType = 1;
   IPAddress = "*";
   Port = 7443;
   OverrideExisting = 1
}
```